# Trouble Centering View using Android ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, constraints, center

I'm having a bit of a problem with ConstraintLayout in Android.

Observe the following illustration:

[image]

I would like to draw your attention to the row of three views across the middle: the TextView, and the two Buttons.

The dotted vertical and horizontal lines are fixed guidelines (expressed in terms of percentage of screen height/width), and are used to constrain these views to.

The TextView is constrained in all 4 directions as you can see.

The Button on the far right is constrained in 3 directions: top, bottom, and right... and has an aspect ratio constraint on it of 1:1.

Now, the Button in the middle is only constrained on top and bottom, and also has an aspect ratio applied of 1:1.

Everything is great so far... but what if we want to *keep everything exactly the same except* center the middle button such that it has equal space to its right and to its left?

One might expect that simply applying horizontal constraints to its nearest neighbors would do the trick... but no.

This is the result:

[image]

So... the size of the button is increasing for some reason.  Why?

It seems to me that Android Studio is applying the 1:1 aspect ratio rule (in this case) by saying "height is a function of width..." that is, width is calculated first (based on the newly applied constraints) and therefore takes precedence.

If it had simply done it the other way around and said "width = height" with height taking precedence... (the same way it was doing prior to those final constraints being applied), then everything would be fine.

So... in other words, how can you center a "middle" view between two other "right" and "left" views and still maintain:

1) All three views have matching heights since they are bound by the same horizontal constraints.

2) The left view is in a fixed position.

3) The right view has a 1:1 aspect ratio and is not allowed to separate from its right-side guideline (fixed position).

?

EDIT:  I have made the following XML snippet for anyone that wants to play with it:

(Remember the three rules above.  Have fun!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.boober.deletethis.MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineH1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.45" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineH2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.55" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineV1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH2"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH2"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="219dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: you question is very clear and understandable, I dont know why people keep voting down your question. they got stressed i think?

Comment: Perhaps... I think it's funny because they don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineH1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.45" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineH2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.55" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineV1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH2"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH1" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but this doesn't seem to work in the specific case where there are horizontal guidelines and 1:1 aspect ratios involved.

Comment: yes it does. I did it before. Can you please share part of your layout code? I will correct it for you

Comment: Ok I'll edit the question to include a code example.

Comment: Yeah, that works!  I didn't think of nesting another ConstraintLayout.